# postgresql json_object_keys(var1) eliminates records where var1 is null

Tags: json, postgresql

I am trying out some of the JSON functionality in postgresql 9.3.4.

I am facing a problem while using json_object_keys(var1), it removes rows where var1 is null.

How can I tweak the query to keep those records as well, populating null in that case

For example, I have a table test1:

```
postgres=# select * from test1;
 var1 |       var2        
------+-------------------
    1 | {"a": 20, "b":30}
    2 | 

postgres=# select var1,json_object_keys(var2) from test1;
 var1 | json_object_keys 
------+------------------
    1 | a
    1 | b
```

I want output to be something like this:

```
postgres=# select var1, json_object_keys(coalesce(var2,'{"": null}')) from test1;
 var1 | json_object_keys 
------+------------------
    1 | a
    1 | b
    2 |
```

Just wanted to know if there is any better way of doing this ?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using PostgreSQL's rather quirky support for set-returning functions in the `SELECT` list, use a lateral query.

I originally wrote the *incorrect* query:

```
select t.var1, k from test1 t, json_object_keys(t.var2) k;
```

but that was wrong, as an implicit `lateral` is a cross-join, and a cross join with zero rows is still zero rows.

You want:

```
SELECT t.var1, k
FROM test1 t 
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
  SELECT t.var1, k 
  FROM json_object_keys(t.var2) k
) lj(var1, k) 
ON (t.var1 = lj.var1);
```

e.g.

```
regress=> CREATE TABLE test1 ( var1 integer, var2 json );
CREATE TABLE
regress=> INSERT INTO test1 (var1, var2) VALUES (1, '{"a": 20, "b":30}'), (2, NULL);
INSERT 0 2
regress=>   SELECT t.var1, k
regress->     FROM test1 t 
regress->     LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
regress(>       SELECT t.var1, k 
regress(>       FROM json_object_keys(t.var2) k
regress(>     ) lj(var1, k) 
regress->     ON (t.var1 = lj.var1);
 var1 | k 
------+---
    1 | a
    1 | b
    2 | 
(3 rows)
```

which evaluates `json_object_keys` for each json field, then does a left join of the result against the input.

Comment: Hi Craig, it still eliminates the record where key is null

Comment: @mandeep_m91 You're quite right. I didn't test, as there was no convenient sample data. I've constructed some and tested then produced a correct query. (Sample data as create table and insert statements or a http://sqlfiddle.com/ is _really_ useful in a question).